# PHP Store unknown array length into database

Tags: php, html, arrays, database, mysqli

So I have a form that lets people add a list of grades, and using jQuery they are able to add up to 9 extra fields. (Meaning they can submit any number from 1 to 10 grades). What I want to know is how I can go about storing this in my database, as I do not want to convert them all into one string. My concern is that because I don't know how many grades the user is going to enter, I can't set a definitive array number to store (or can I?)

Sorry if this is not terribly well explained, I'm still relatively new to PHP and SQL!

Comment: As it is currently written it is unclear what you're asking. Can you add more information what you currently have (form, php script, database scheme, table relationships...)?

Comment: Grades should be one table linked to the owner of each grade. You can have as many rows in the grade table as you need with three columns - student identifier, course and grade.

Comment: So I have a 'grades' table which relates to a CV table, and the CV table relates to a user table. Meaning many grades within one CV/resume, and many CV/resumes for one user. For example they currently upload something like Maths, A, GCSE as one entry and English, A*, A Level as another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick assumption if I am not mistaken would be: saving one user with multiple grades for multiple subjects can be achieved like this.

Firstly we get one user id from the form and put it in PHP:

```
$id = isset($_POST['id'])? $_POST['id']:'';
```

Then get multiple grades and subjects which would be sent as comma separated values:

```
//$id= explode(',',$_POST['id']);// For multiple users
$grade= explode(',',$_POST['grade']);
$subj= explode(',',$_POST['subject']);
$entry= explode(',',$_POST['entry']);
```

Now count the number of grades: `$count= count($grade);`

Use the count in a `for loop` to have insert in loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
   try {
        $dbh->beginTransaction();   //$dbh is your PDO connection               
            $insertQ = "INSERT INTO `grades` (id, grade, subject, entry) 
                        VALUES('$id', '$grade[$i]', '$subj[$i]','$entry[$i])";             
            $dbh->query($insertQ);              
            $dbh->commit();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $error = $e->getMessage();

            }
}
```

Hope this may help.